# Запрос с объединением таблиц

Tags: sql-server, sql

Скажем, у нас есть вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT [first_name],[middle_name],[last_name],[group_name],[id_subgroup],[count_steps],[start_testing],[finish_testing]
FROM [user] JOIN [test] ON [user].[id_user] = [test].[id_user]
            JOIN [groups] ON [groups].[id_group] = [test].[id_group]
```

И есть другая таблица, у которой есть, к примеру, 2 колонки: `[id_user] и [num_step]`
(к одному `[id_user]` могут быть привязаны много `[num_step]`) . Мне нужно выбрать из данной таблицы только те строчки, у которых `[num_step]` - максимален для данного `[id_user]`. 
И подсоединить преобразованную таблицу к первым 3-м таблицам (JOIN). Саму выборку сделать просто:

```
SELECT MAX([num_step]),[id_user] 
FROM [step]
GROUP BY [id_user]
```

А вот как потом сделать JOIN по `[id_user]`, я не знаю.
И если можно, 2-ой вопрос: как сделать выборку из таблицы, которая есть разность значений 2-ух колонок?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT [first_name],[middle_name],[last_name],[group_name],[id_subgroup],[count_steps],[start_testing],[finish_testing], max([num_step])
FROM [user] JOIN [test] ON [user].[id_user] = [test].[id_user]
            JOIN [groups] ON [groups].[id_group] = [test].[id_group]
            JOIN [step] ON [user].[id_user] = [step].[id_user]
GROUP BY
  [first_name],[middle_name],[last_name],[group_name],
  [id_subgroup],[count_steps],[start_testing],[finish_testing]
```

или вложенным запросом:

```
SELECT [first_name],[middle_name],[last_name],[group_name],[id_subgroup],[count_steps],[start_testing],[finish_testing], [step_max].[max_step]
FROM [user] JOIN [test] ON [user].[id_user] = [test].[id_user]
            JOIN [groups] ON [groups].[id_group] = [test].[id_group]
            JOIN (SELECT max([num_step]) as [max_step], [id_user] 
                  FROM [step] 
                  GROUP BY [id_user]) as [step_max] 
              ON [user].[id_user] = [step_max].[id_user]
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT MAX(step.num_step), user.* FROM step INNER JOIN user ON user.id_user = step.id_user JOIN [test] ON [user].[id_user] = [test].[id_user] JOIN [groups] ON [groups].[id_group] = [test].[id_group] GROUP BY step.id_user
```

А насчет второго вопроса не совсем понятно, что вас затрудняет:

```
select (col1 - col2) as `raznost_dvuh_kolonok` from table WHERE (col1 - col2) = 5
```

Comment: Хм,интересно, но почему-то после 1-го запроса выскакивает ошибка:
Column 'user.id_user' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
То есть выборка каких-либо колонок всех таблиц кроме [step] вызывает почему-то ошибки

Comment: Я вот тестирую такой запрос на своей (подобной) базе и у меня такой запрос проходит нормально, т.е. возвращается максимум step.num_step для данного user_id:

     SELECT MAX(step.num_step), user.* FROM step INNER JOIN user ON user.id_user = step.id_user GROUP BY user.id_user

От вашего он отличается только наличием еще двух джоинов.

Попробуйте добавить user.id_user в GROUP BY (http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/u.cgi/err979/sqlserver). Хотя у меня хоть с ним, хоть без него работает.

Comment: в group by нужно перечислять все поля из select'а, по которым нет агрегатной функции. после добавления конкретно user_id из этой ошибки будет следующая ошибка про first_name и т.д. поэтому использование ``select *`` в запросах с агрегатными функциями использовать не стоит. лучше перечислять выбираемые поля в запросе, потом их же перечислять в group by. иначе если структура таблицы поменяется (добавится поле например) запрос опять будет выдавать ошибку и искать все такие места будет довольно хлопотно.

Comment: Ну не знаю, не знаю... Может вы и правы, но у меня то все работает и без этого. Я как бэ... не стал бы нарочно распространять ложные утверждения тоже...

Comment: Хотя это может из-за того, что у меня mysql...

Comment: Достаточно почитать сообщение об ошибке. То, что mysql позволяет такое... ну он еще позволяет вообще не писать group by. В других субд могут быть другие варианты. Синтаксис group by везде примерно одинаков, не стоит этим пренебрегать, даже если в mysql все работает...

Comment: Да я если честно только что увидел что вопрос по mssql. По собственной глупости. Так что извиняюсь....

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
SELECT [first_name],[middle_name],[last_name],[group_name],[id_subgroup],[count_steps],[start_testing],[finish_testing]
FROM [user] JOIN [test] ON [user].[id_user] = [test].[id_user]
            JOIN [groups] ON [groups].[id_group] = [test].[id_group]
JOIN (
SELECT MAX([num_step]) m_st,[id_user] 
FROM [step]
GROUP BY [id_user] ) X ON [user].[id_user] = X.[id_user]
```